# How to organise many ajax requests self dependent

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an app in JS. It will store data in one object through many ajax calls to other site.

So, I make a call, receive some data and put it in a variabile. Then I do other call using previus data. There will be many calls based on previus data.

I did some functions for every call and tryed to execute them one by one, but I see that when next function is executed the previus one may not be finished yet and data is not available.

I know that there are callback functions, but I can't make every next function to be called by callback from previus one, because I need to run or not some of them depending on data.

Please help me, tell me how to organise my app or tell me where to read about it. I even don't know what to write to google to find what I need.

Comment: How many request do you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are making ajax request, but ajax request are not syncronous, then you need to use callback inside your functions to control when a function was finished.

You can use some jquery functions that encapsulate this so you can made any effort to have the same behavior.

You need to create an array of function that are not dependent of any data or other functions:

```
    var deferreds = [];

    $.each(views, function(index, view) {
        deferreds.push($.get('url_that_you_want_to_call', function(data) {
                // treat your data as you wish
        }));
    });
```

Then you can pass this array to be executed and you can control when they are finished:

```
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
```

You need to repeat this process until all your request are done.

[This answer was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013967/how-do-you-determine-if-an-asynchronous-function-is-completed-in-before-executin)

Comment: Yes cascading asynchronous requests. but functions must not be executed one by one because some of them may not be exec depending on data received.

Comment: now it looks like this but it does not work like i want
   ` store_data = {


    run: function(){
         func1();
         if (store_data.data.foo == bar)
         {
            func2();
         }
         if(...){func3()}
    }
    
        func1: function(){
            do_reqwest(/*callback func*/ function(r){store_data.data =   r})
        }
    
        func2: function(){
            do_reqwest(/*callback func*/ function(r){store_data.data1 = r})
        }
    
        func3: function(){
            do_reqwest(/*callback func*/ function(r){store_data.data2 = r})
        }
    }`

Comment: I improve the clarity of my answered so you can better understand, my point.